# How can I change labels from sj_plot?

Tags: r, sjplot

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p2coN.png)

Can anybody tell me how to change the labels from "cntry (Intercept)" and "lrscale"?
I have been trying for hours and can't fix it.

I tried different approaches from ggplot and baseR, nothing worked.

Comment: Oh man, thank you so much! That solved my issues, which cost me many nerves!